# Get Real Time - Not Device Set Time in android

Tags: android, datetime, real-time, time-format

How to find out the *Real Geographical Time*, as in my application I want to attach the real time with my application.

So that if the user changes the time in his device then I should get only the real prevailing time - NOT THE DEVICE TIME

My question is much confusing but try to understand in a simple language -

**I dont want DEVICE TIME, I want REAL PREVAILING TIME at any instant**

Comment: @penguat I just want to know what is the real time, not UTC or GMT time

Comment: Do you mean the local time at the device's location?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by real time?

Answer (score 13):

**You need to use the NTP (Network Time Protocol) protocol:**

Here is some code I found somewhere else... and I am using it. This uses the Apache Commons library, which can be installed using Gradle (adding a dependency on `commons-net:commons-net:3.6`)

If you need a list of time servers, check: http://tf.nist.gov/service/time-servers.html

Here is some Java Code for you to use:

```
public class TimeLookup {
    public static final String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);
        System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
    }

}
```

Note the Android code must run on the background thread and include gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

Comment: In my case, the valid timestamp was found using: timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime()

Comment: long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime();

Comment: older post, but it´s important here: Stefano is right. If getting time like showed in the post, it returns (described in API) **...time message packet was received by local machine** . It seems that this returns the device time, I tried it. But if you use `timeInfo.getMessage().getReceiveTimeStamp().getTime()` , you get (described in API) **...the receive time as defined in RC_1305** which is the net time no matter what is defined in device..

Comment: Even if you use this method, changing the time on the phone will cause the NTPUDPClient to give you that time instead of the time from the host.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Android API to get you such a time. The user can always change the device time, nothing you can do about that.

Your best bet would be to run a server with a webservice, from which you can get the time. Since you control the server, you can try to ensure it returns the correct time.

Comment: can we use joda time lib?

Comment: The data that I receive has an expiry (20sec) how do I make sure the device time I am comparing it with is correct without forcing the user to enable 'automatic time' for this device.

Answer (score 0):

Next code worked with me to get real date even if device has wrong date.
Thanks to @Stefano.

```kotlin
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


object DateOperation {

    private const val TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov"
    const val DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    suspend fun getRealDay(): String {
        val timeClient = NTPUDPClient()
        val inetAddress: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER)
        val timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress)
        val returnTime = timeInfo.message.receiveTimeStamp.date
        val t = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN, Locale.ENGLISH)
        return t.format(returnTime)
    }
}
```

after adding dependency:

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

Then use it like

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val date = getRealDay()
            Log.d("TestTest", "onCreate: $date")

        }

    }
```

`